# IIS problem regarding missing assembly

Tags: iis, asp.net-2.0, .net-assembly

I am getting the following error while trying to load an ASP.net website on IIS.

I created a virtual directory for the website, and though my website contains no reference to any assembly ( I even tried a blank ASP.net website with 1 button) but still with no use.

I am using Windows server 2003 64-bit edition.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be available in your **web.config** file under `<assemblies>` and hence IIS is trying to load it.

In addition you can download report viewer installer from [HERE](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=8A166CAC-758D-45C8-B637-DD7726E61367&displaylang=en) and then try to run your website, it should work once this assembly is available in GAC.